# How does QuickBooks online determine the ExpenseAccountRef.value? Do I need to QUERY an ACCOUNT object to determine the value?

Tags: api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

My app will use QuickBooks Online API to to "Create a NonInventory Item"

I don't understand how this value is determined.
Do I have to initialize my NonInventory Item with an ExpenseAccountRef.value? 
Should I QUERY the ACCOUNT object to determine which values exist before initializing a new one?

Below is an example of the required fields:

```
{ 
  "Name": "Garden Supplies",  
  "Type": "NonInventory", 
  "ExpenseAccountRef": { 
    "value": "80"
  }
}
```

In the documentation (found at: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/item), it states:
**ExpenseAccountRef**
"Reference to the expense account used to pay the vendor for this item. Must be an account with account type of Cost of Goods Sold. Query the Account name list resource to determine the appropriate Account object for this reference. Use Account.Id and Account.Name from that object for ExpenseAccountRef.value and ExpenseAccountRef.name, respectively."

**value** *String*
"The ID for the referenced object as found in the Id field of the object payload. The context is set by the type of reference and is specific to the QuickBooks company file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to initialize my NonInventory Item with an ExpenseAccountRef.value?

Is it marked as a required field in the documentation? If so, then yes.

> Should I QUERY the ACCOUNT object to determine which values exist before initializing a new one?

Yes. The docs you quoted indicate this as well:

"Query the Account name list resource to determine the appropriate Account object for this reference. Use Account.Id and Account.Name from that object for ExpenseAccountRef.value and ExpenseAccountRef.name, respectively."

Comment: Do you know how the ExpenseAccountRef.value is determined? Can this value be declared or initialized through the QBO API or is this value automatically assigned by QuickBooks?

Comment: All `Id` values are assigned by QuickBooks. You cannot define them yourself. When you (or anyone else) creates an `Account`, it will be assigned a unique `Id` value. You can query the `Accounts` list via the API to get the `Id` values (and other data).